# Drop database before anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I have seen many answer to this question but any of these work for me and I don't know why.

So I want to delete all data in my database before running the tests and after add some. This is what I've done so far :

```
const db = require('../models');

describe('Setup database for testing', () => {
    before('Sync and create data', done => {
        db.sequelize
            .query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0', null, {raw: true})
            .then(() => {
                db.User.sync({force: true});
            })

            // Create everything the tests need here
            .then(() => {
                db.User.create({username: 'foo', password: 'secret', email: 'foo@local.dev'});
            })

            .then(() => {
                db.sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1', null, {raw: true});
            })
            .then(() => {
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

When I run mocha on my test folder, I have no errors, nothing telling me the before hook is running (even the test title doesn't show). But the file is running because when I write dummy code in it, I have the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least one test within the describe for the before hook to run.

```
  describe('Setup database for testing', () => {
    before('Sync and create data', done => {
        db.sequelize
            .query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0', null, {raw: true})
            .then(() => {
                db.User.sync({force: true});
            })

            // Create everything the tests need here
            .then(() => {
                db.User.create({username: 'foo', password: 'secret', email: 'foo@local.dev'});
            })

            .then(() => {
                db.sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1', null, {raw: true});
            })
            .then(() => {
                done();
            });
    });


    //add a test for the before hook to run 
    it("runs", function () {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But now I have the error `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`, or I do the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`...